# Google oauth 2.0 - do i need refresh token?

Tags: php, google-oauth

On my webpage i have simple login system (PHP). You provide mail and password, system create _SESSION and you are logged.

I want to add option for login with google oAuth 2.0.

I created **index.php** file:

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
$redirect_uri = '/login.php';
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

<a href="<?=$client->createAuthUrl()?>">LOGIN WITH GOOGLE</a>
```

User will click on link, after choose a google account he is redirected to:

**login.php** file:

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    try {
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        //redirect to login.php - invalid login
        exit();
    }

    try {
        $pay_load = $client->verifyIdToken();
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        //redirect to login.php - invalid login
        exit();
    }
    //NOW I KNOW USER IS VALID,
    //create my own _SESSION and redirect to index.php as logged user (i will use mail and name of user from google). 
    // i am managing _SESSION so if user logOut i will just destroy session, or will be destroyed after few minutes of inactivity
}
```

Is this approach good?

Do i need use

```
setAccessToken($token);
verifyIdToken();
```

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are miss understanding the difference between **Authorization** and **authentication**.

`Oauth2 grants you authorization to access a users data is denoted by an access token and a refresh token.`  Refresh tokens allow you to access a users data when the user is offline by requesting a new access token. Using Oauth2 does not garentee  that there is a user behind the calls being made.

`OpenId connect Authenticates is a user logging in and authenticating using a login and password or google login that this is the user.`   This is denoted by an Id token.  There will always be the actual user behind a login to open id connect.

> On my webpage i have simple login system (PHP). You provide mail and password, system create _SESSION and you are logged.

If you are working with a login system then you should be using openid connect which does not really need a refresh token to access the user data when the user is offline.  The user will always be present in a login system.

Comment: So after 
`$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);`
i add
`$client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);`
and then i can use function 
`$google_data = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);`
to get the user data. 
Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If the main question here is, "will I need the refresh token?" the answer to that is... the access token will expire. Once it expires you will have two options:

1. Put the user through the login process again.
2. Use the refresh token to get a new access token.

The sole purpose of refresh tokens is to obtain fresh access tokens after expiry, without having to redirect a user to google and back again. If you don't mind doing that, or if you only need access to their accounts for a short time, you will not really need to use the refresh token.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I need only 20 minutes and expire time in oAuth is i think 60 so it is enough.